# Is there a datagrid mouse down hit test to get the row and column index of the click?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, hittest

With Winforms' `DataGridView`, one could use `HitTest` to determine the column and row index of the mouse down (and other events).

```
Dim hti As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = sender.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
```

Is there something similar with WPF's `DataGrid`? I need to get the row and column indexes for the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than this but the following links should be helpful in getting the index of the row and column.

**WPF DataGrid - detecting the column, cell and row that has been clicked:** http://blog.scottlogic.com/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html

[WPF DataGrid - get row number which mouse cursor is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502150/wpf-datagrid-get-row-number-which-mouse-cursor-is-on)

You will have to use the VisualTreeHelper class to traverse the Visual elements that make up the DataGrid as explained above.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried about 3 different C to VB converters and non have been able to convert that code to VB

Answer (score -1):

For those that may wish to avoid my search here is the total code I ended up puzzling together that is able to deliver:

1. Current row index
2. Current Column index
3. Current Column header And
4. is able to expose the value/s of columns on the row.

   The code goes into MouseLeftButtonup event and DGrid1 is the name of the grid

   ```
   Dim currentRowIndex As Integer = -1
   Dim CurrentColumnIndex As Integer = -1
   Dim CurrentColumnHeader As String = ""
   Dim Myrow As DataRowView = Nothing
   Dim dep As DependencyObject = DirectCast(e.OriginalSource, DependencyObject)
   While dep IsNot Nothing And Not TypeOf dep Is DataGridCell And Not TypeOf dep Is Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader
       dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep)
       If dep IsNot Nothing Then
           If TypeOf dep Is DataGridCell Then
               Dim cell As DataGridCell = DirectCast(dep, DataGridCell)
               Dim col As DataGridBoundColumn = DirectCast(cell.Column, DataGridBoundColumn)
               Myrow = DGrid1.SelectedItem
               CurrentColumnHeader = col.Header.ToString
               CurrentColumnIndex = col.DisplayIndex
               currentRowIndex = DGrid1.Items.IndexOf(DGrid1.CurrentItem)
               Exit While
           End If
       End If
   End While
   If currentRowIndex = -1 OrElse CurrentColumnIndex = -1 OrElse CurrentColumnHeader = "" OrElse Myrow Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        'code to consume the variables from here

   Dim strinwar As String = Myrow.Item("header name or index").ToString()
   ```